# Inserting non-duplicate rows into the table with partition by in sql

Tags: sql, oracle

There are two table `x_ass_table` and `i_ass_table` :

I am inserting data from `x_ass_table` with 1128 records to `i_ass_table`. To avoid the unique constraint error I am using the following query :

```
     insert assignment_number, 
            effective_start_date,
            effective_end_date,
            effective_latest_change,
            configuration_no 
     into i_ass_table
          select effective_start_date,
                 effective_end_date,
                 effective_latest_change,
                 'XX_FUS' 
      FROM     (SELECT x_ass_table.*,
                       COUNT() OVER (PARTITION BY assignment_number, 
                                                  effective_start_date,
                                                  effective_end_date,
                                                  effective_latest_change) AS c
                FROM   x_ass_table) t
    where c=1;
```

Still I am getting the unique constraint error. Though i have restricted the `assignment_number, effective_start_date,effective_end_date,effective_latest_change`columns which were unique key columns.

Comment: Are you sure the columns match? You are selecting an additional column besides the ones in `x_ass_table` (your count). This would of course give a different error message, so wouldn't be a solution to stated problem

Comment: I have edited my query @HoneyBadger

Comment: Still a mismatch in columns, I guess you forgot `assignment_number`

Comment: If those are all the columns you need, can't you just use `distinct`?

Comment: @HoneyBadger there are around 20 columns... I have shortened the query for better understanding

Comment: Perhaps there are already records in `i_ass_table` with the same values, can you check?

Comment: @HoneyBadger - That table is empty

Comment: If you run the query as a `select`, can you identify the not-unique records?

Comment: @HoneyBadger- Yes i am getting the unque and non-unique records but when I am inserting it its going into error with unique key violation

Comment: If you select, can you see something odd, perhaps null values? Can you post some sample data?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are checking duplicate records present in `x_ass_table`, but you should also check if there is same records present in `i_ass_table` and `x_ass_table`. That can also create unique constraint error.

```
    select *  
      from x_ass_table x,  
           i_ass_table i  
    where i.assignment_number = x.assignment_number  
      and i.effective_start_date = x.effective_start_date  
      and i.effective_end_date = x.effective_end_date  
      and i.effective_latest_change = x.effective_latest_change;
```

Comment: I_ASS_TABLE is empty.. but i resolved the issue. It was because of some discrepancy in data. Took quiet a while because the count of the data was too many